# Detect click on any child node and get its ID attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the ID of a child node of an element when the parent node has many child nodes?

```
<div id="parentID">
    <div id="id_1"></div>
    <div id="id_2"></div>
    <div id="id_3"></div>
    ...
    <div id="id_n"></div>
</div>
```

In the above code example, how can I get the ID of any child node when the user clicks it?

Answer (score 4):

Assign an `eventListener` to the parent element and when clicking on the child
element retrieve their id attribute. Here is a code sample:

```js
document.getElementById('parentID').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
})
```

```html
<div id="parentID">
  <div id="id_1">id1</div>
  <div id="id_2">id2</div>
  <div id="id_3">id3</div>

  <div id="id_n">idn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: best answer for me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) in the dom [propagate](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) and move from child to parent evnetually.

You can add a single event listener and check its target property. This technique of adding a single event listener and routing based on children is called event delegation.

```js
document.querySelector("#parentID").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // e is an event object
  // e.target; is whomever was actually clicked
  if (e.target.id === 'id_1') {
    // do something specific.
  }
});
```

Note that in general having sequential IDs in your code is a code smell indicating bad separation of concerns. So make sure you know it's the right thing to do before doing it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

```
function byid( e ){ return document.getElementById( e ); }
var id1 = byid( "id_1" ),
    id2 = byid( "id_2" ),
    id3 = byid( "id_3" ),
    id4 = byid( "id_4" );
[id1,id2,id3,id4].forEach( e => {
    e.addEventListener( "click",getId );
    function getid( e ){
        alert( e.getAttribute( "id" ) );
    }
} );
```